# Unable to upload video size more than 50 Mb in GCP clourd un and loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

I have connected the backend(cloud run) and frontend(cloud run) with a GCP load balancer,
when I try to update a video file of size > 50Mb via backend API to google cloud storage, I am below getting, is there a way to increase the payload size??

```
Error: Request Entity Too Large
Your client issued a request that was too large.
```

when we had the same issue with the Nginx setup instead of the load balancer I used the client_max_body_size parameter to increase the size. Is there any parameter to increase client_max_body_size in GCP load balancer or cloud run

Answer (score 0):

The maximum HTTP payload size is 32 MB which includes HTTP headers. That limit cannot be increased.

Comment: I have an SSL cert will that change payload size.

Comment: @MohamedAnserAli - No, an SSL certificate will not change payload size. Why would you think it would? The limit cannot be changed.

Comment: @JohnHanley is the solution to use nginx?

Comment: @user2763557 - Nginx would not increase the HTTP payload limits.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks. what would be the potential fix for this?

Comment: @user2763557 The payload limit is imposed on the service. You would need to use a different strategy, such as Cloud Storage, or use a different service such as Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation the limit is 64 KB. Request url and header

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#https-lb-header-limits

Comment: is the solution to use nginx?

Comment: Note for those reading this answer. The link is for a different product and does not apply to Cloud Run.